# Creating a Dynamic List of Buttons from data contained in an array

Tags: android

I am working on making an application for taking basketball stats.  I am currently working on allowing the person who is taking stats to setwho will be in/out at the start of the game.  I also plan to reuse this code later on so that the person can sub people in and out during the game.  Anyway, I am stuck on how to create the list of buttons based on the size of an array.

Currently, I have an array set up to pull the player's number, name, and whether they are in/out from the team's database.  The buttons would display the player's number so that they could be subbed in and out.  I would like to have it set up so that when a person clicks on one of the buttons, it would change who is considered "in" for the game and also update the values in the database.  I'll put what little source code I have below.  I have tried many approaches such as a gridview, looping through a button creation command and several other things but have been unable to get any of them to work the way I would like.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Activity to set who is on the bench:

```
package com.newelementapp.basketballstatbook;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class HomeBench extends Activity {


    String tname, t1, t2;
    String [] players;
    LinearLayout ll;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_bench);
        Bundle rteam = getIntent().getExtras();
        tname = rteam.getString("team");
        StatbookDB get = new StatbookDB(this);
        get.open();
        players = get.getHomePlayers(tname);
        get.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

DB:

```
public String[] getHomePlayers(String tname) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String [] columns = {KEY_PNUMBER, KEY_PNAME, KEY_INOUT};
        List<String> hplayers2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        String teamname = tname.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "_");
        Cursor c  = ourDatabase.query(teamname, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

        int inum = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PNUMBER);
        int iname = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PNAME);
        int iout = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_INOUT);
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            String s = c.getString(iname);
            String i = c.getString(inum);
            String t = c.getString(iout);
            hplayers2.add(i);
            hplayers2.add(s);
            hplayers2.add(t);
        }
        String [] hplayers = new String[hplayers2.size()];
        hplayers2.toArray(hplayers);
        return hplayers;
    }
```

Button Creation method

```
private void createButtons() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i = 0; i<players.length; i+=3){
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        btn.setId(i);
        btn.setText(players[i]);
        ll.addView(btn, params);
        btn1=(Button)findViewById(i);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ... }
```

Comment: When you say - "I have tried many approaches such as a gridview, looping through a button creation command and several other things but have been unable to get any of them to work the way I would like." So, you are able to create the buttons but when you click on the buttons, you are unable to get the functionality like you wish? Or is it that you are not even able to create and display the buttons as per your layout goals?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What is not working? Any errors? Exceptions?

Comment: @Harikris and Adnan Mulla, I have been unable to create the buttons and achieve the desired functionality.  I have looked at many different articles/Stack overflow questions on the subject, but have been unable to even find a place to start.  I am fairly new to Android, but do have an understanding of the basics.

Comment: @NewElement Post your code where you say you are creating Buttons by looping. Key is to have a ViewGroup such as a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout in your home_bench.xml file. This ViewGroup will become your container. Then when you loop around and dynamically create the Buttons, you keep adding those buttons to the container ViewGroup. Then you will be able to see the Buttons you are creating. Also, after you create the button, use setOnClickListener() on those buttons to specify a onClick routine where you define what to do when buttons are clicked. Use ids to differentiate between buttons.

Comment: @NewElement If the comment helped, let me know and i will turn that into an answer so that it might help others as well.

Comment: @Harikris Thanks so much.  I'm putting the updated code above in the opening post.  And yes, I would like you to turn your comment into an answer that way it might help others out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key is to have a `ViewGroup` such as a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` in your `home_bench.xml` file. This `ViewGroup` will become your container. Then when you loop around and dynamically create the `Buttons`, you keep adding those buttons to the container ViewGroup. Then you will be able to see the Buttons you are creating. Also, after you create the button, use `setOnClickListener()` on those buttons to specify a onClick routine where you define what to do when buttons are clicked. Use `ids` to differentiate between buttons. You would assign an id to a button when you are creating the button. HTH.